# Text SVG stroke-dasharray length different from Chrome to Safari

Tags: svg, stroke-dasharray

I have the followint SVG Text that I want to animate. No issue on the animation, however the length of the dash-array differs from Chrome to Safari (not tested else where yet).

Note that the stroke-dasharray works at 87 on Chrome and at 837 on Safari. Why is it different?

```css
#chrome{
   stroke-dasharray: 87;
   stroke-dashoffset: 87;
   transition: .5s;
}

#chrome:hover{
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

#safari{
   stroke-dasharray: 837;
   stroke-dashoffset: 837;
   transition: .5s;
}

#safari:hover{
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

```html
Chrome: Hover below.
<svg width="500" viewBox="0 0 102 17">
    
    <text id="chrome" x="0" y="13" stroke-width=".2" stroke="red" fill="none">Web Design.</text>

</svg>
<br>
Safari: Hover below.
<svg width="500" viewBox="0 0 102 17">
    
    <text id="safari" x="0" y="13" stroke-width=".2" stroke="red" fill="none">Web Design.</text>

</svg>
```

Comment: Are you using the same fonts? And is this WIndows vs. Mac or are you doing both on Mac? Default fonts are not standard across browsers or platforms - which could be making the difference.

Comment: If your text is not dynamic (changes at runtime), then convert it to paths. Problem solved.

Comment: @MichaelMullany Both on Mac, and same font.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Ideally I want ot have it as TEXT for SEO purposes.

Comment: @stemon Do you need search engines to actually index the text in `<text>` elements?  In most cases, providing appropriate content `in <title>` and/or `<desc>` elements would be sufficient.